# MySQL CURSOR not fetching desired rows

Tags: mysql, cursor

The below code is only looping through the cursor once, and in that one loop, it is setting product_name and list_price to null.  I have run that SELECT statement (the one for the CURSOR) by itself and it returns 4 results.  I am unsure how or why it does not loop through all 4 times and why, on its single loop that it is doing, is not using the first records values for product_name and list_price

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE retString VARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE rowNotFound TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE product_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE list_price DECIMAL(10,2);

    DECLARE prodCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT product_name, list_price FROM products WHERE list_price > 700 ORDER BY list_price DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
        SET rowNotFound = TRUE;

    OPEN prodCursor;

    WHILE rowNotFound = FALSE DO
        FETCH prodCursor INTO product_name, list_price;
        SET retString = CONCAT(retString, '"', product_name, '","' , list_price, '"|');
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE prodCursor;

    SELECT retString AS 'Message';
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL test();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following ended up being the answer.  I had two problems, first the comparisons in the SELECT statement needed to be quantified better and (as @spencer7593 pointed out) retString was initialized to null.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
    DECLARE retString VARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE rowNotFound TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE product_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE list_price DECIMAL(10,2);

    DECLARE prodCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT p.product_name, p.list_price FROM products p WHERE p.list_price > 700.00 ORDER BY p.list_price DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
        SET rowNotFound = TRUE;

    SET retString = '';
    OPEN prodCursor;

    WHILE rowNotFound = FALSE DO
        FETCH prodCursor INTO product_name, list_price;
        SET retString = CONCAT(retString, '"', product_name, '","' , list_price, '"|');
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE prodCursor;

    SELECT retString AS 'Message';
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `retString` is initialized to `NULL`.

And we know the expression:

```
  CONCAT(NULL,'something')
```

evaluates to `NULL`.  No matter how many non-NULL values we add, it's still gonna be NULL.

Try initializing `retString` to a non-NULL value before the loop.

```
  SET retString = 'foo';
```

And see what you get. I suspect that starting with an empty string will get you what you are after:

```
  SET retString = '';
```

This could also be specified as a `DEFAULT` for the procedure variable, instead of a separate `SET` statement.

If *any* of the arguments in the `CONCAT` function evaluate to NULL, then CONCAT will return `NULL`. (Consider what happens when `product_name` or `list_price` is NULL.)  MySQL has a handy function for testing for a NULL value and returning something else...

```
 IFNULL(foo,'bar')
```

is shorthand for   `IF(foo IS NULL,'bar',foo)`